# VBA Refresh Queries Then Adjust Column Width

Tags: excel, vba, events, excel-2016, column-width

I am attempting to run a code upon opening the workbook that asks the user if they would like to refresh the data. If so, then it will refresh the data and then adjust the columns to the correct sizes (I do not want autofit).

My problem is that the columns to do not get adjusted when doing a full run on the macro. If you step through, it works fine. Any advice is appreciated!

FINAL UPDATE: This works on the Retail Home and Business version of Excel. Not on the version I am currently using. (It is Microsoft Office Standard 2016.) Boy was that a frustrating revelation!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Result
Result = MsgBox("The Data in this document might be outdated. Would you like to refresh the Data Queries? This process could take a few minutes...", vbYesNo, "Data Query OutDated")
If Result = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "Queries Will Refresh Upon Closing this window. Please wait."

Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = False
Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").EnableCalculation = False

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

MsgBox "Refresh Complete"

Worksheets("RMData").Activate
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 41.57
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 26.14
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 14.57
    Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 14.57
Worksheets("PMData").Activate
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 12.86
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.14
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 9.43
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 16.57
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 37.42
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 10.57
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 12.29
    Columns("R:R").ColumnWidth = 12.29
    Columns("S:S").ColumnWidth = 10.29
    Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 18.14
End Sub
```

Comment: fully qualify your ranges rather than relying on the "activate".  So it should be "Worksheets("RMData").Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 41.57", etc.  Which can be cleaned up using a 'with' statement, but I'll leave that research up to you.

Comment: @sous2817 That did not solve my issue. Still having the cells seemingly revert back to the size the refresh wants them to be at.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code slightly and disable the query refresh on the background

Also added some basic error handling

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' Set basic error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Turn off stuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").EnableCalculation = False
    
    ' Ask user to proceed with updating process
    Dim userAnswer As Long
    userAnswer = MsgBox("The Data in this document might be outdated." & Chr(13) & _
                        "Would you like to refresh the Data Queries?" & Chr(13) & _
                        "This process could take a few minutes...", vbYesNo, "Data Query OutDated")
    
    ' Exit sub if not
    If userAnswer = vbNo Then GoTo CleanExit
    
    MsgBox "Queries Will Refresh Upon Closing this window. Please wait."
    
    ' Change background refresh so process waits until all queries are done refreshing
    Change_Background_Refresh False
    
    ' Refresh all queries
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    ' Set columns widths
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RMData")
        .Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 41.57
        .Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 26.14
        .Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 14.57
        .Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 14.57
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PMData")
        .Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 12.86
        .Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.14
        .Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 9.43
        .Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 16.57
        .Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 37.42
        .Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 8
        .Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 8.43
        .Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 10.57
        .Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 12.29
        .Columns("R:R").ColumnWidth = 12.29
        .Columns("S:S").ColumnWidth = 10.29
        .Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 18.14
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Refresh Complete" & Chr(13) & _
            "Reenabling screenupdating and calculations..."
    
CleanExit:
    ' Turn on stuff again
    Change_Background_Refresh True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").EnableCalculation = True
    Exit Sub
    
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "An error occurred:" & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub

Private Sub Change_Background_Refresh(ByVal enableBGRefresh As Boolean)
'Description: Enable or disable background refresh on all Power Query connections
'Author: Jon Acampora, Excel Campus
'Source:  https://www.excelcampus.com/library/enable-background-refresh-on-all-power-query-connections/
   
Dim lCnt As Long

    'The following code loops through all connections
    'in the active workbook.  Change the property to
    'True to Enable, False to Disable background refresh.
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        For lCnt = 1 To .Connections.Count
          'Excludes PowerPivot and other connections
          If .Connections(lCnt).Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
            .Connections(lCnt).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = enableBGRefresh
          End If
        Next lCnt
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: So seems like its the exact same issue as the other answer. The columns are changed by the manual section and then forced to what the refresh wants right when the macro ends.

Comment: You can right click the table and in properties uncheck the adjust columns widths

Comment: That is already unchecked. Out of the 4, options, I only have Preserve Cell Formatting on